# Cos (x): non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r

```
> P=makeFun(7.5*(4.1-0.5*cos(x))/(0.5*sin(x))~x)
> D(P(x)~x)
Error in cos(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I've been trying to create a function and it's giving me an error. I've tried a bunch of things with this function, and none of them work. I can plug a number into P, but I can't take it's derivative. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the `makeFun` function come from? Are you using some package? That's not the standard way to make an R function.

Comment: That's what we were taught to do in class. It's in the Mosaic package. What's the standard way?

Comment: A more standard way is something like `p<-function(x) {2*cos(x)+.5*sin(x)}; p(5)` but i'm sure your teacher must have a reason for using mosaic

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was amusing. First I discovered that the package name is `mosaic`, not Mosaic. After loading it and looking at the ?D page, I get no error:

```
 install.packages("mosaic", dependencies=TRUE)
 load(mosaic)
 P=makeFun(7.5*(4.1-0.5*cos(x))/(0.5*sin(x))~x)
 D(P(x)~x)
#--------
function (x) 
7.5 * (0.5 * sin((x)))/(0.5 * sin((x))) - 7.5 * (4.1 - 0.5 * 
    cos((x))) * (0.5 * cos((x)))/(0.5 * sin((x)))^2
```

You should now try to debug the problem by first determining if all the dependencies for the package available. I also had no object named "x" in my workspace, so you may wnat to execute `rm(x) and try re-running, since it appears that the evaluator is finding an "x" it doesn't like. (But I was not able to create that error by assigning a character value to 'x'.) I'm on a Mac running 3.1.0 Patched.

Comment: I was not able to get the error either http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=JnNlqmdT&version=1

Comment: An R Chrome app? How cute is that!?